# iPad Pro stuck on iOS 13.7

Tags: software-update

Ive got a gen1 iPad Pro with iPadOS 13.7 on it. But when I go to General and Software update, it tells me there’s no update available. Is this correct? Shouldnt I be getting iOS 14?

Comment: Did you reboot the iPad in case something got stuck?

Answer (score 2):

The first generation iPad Pro definitely supports iPadOS 14.

Ensure that you have a working internet connection, and try Settings > General > Software Update again.

If that doesn't work, try shutting down the iPad and power it on again - and try Software Update again.

If that still doesn't work, check if you have a beta software profile installed on the iPad (if you have previously been testing beta versions of iPadOS).

If everything fails, you could restore the iPadOS software to the iPad from a computer.